# JMeter: CSS Extractor transfers wrong __VIEWSTATE-value to the Login Page

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to log in into a ASP.NET website and can not transfer the right __VIEWSTATE to the Login Page. I am trying for hours now and cant seem to find what Im doing wrong.

Problem:
I have a start page where the VIEWSTATE is created and have to pass it to the login page where i then

First I added a CSS Extractor with following configuration:
[CSS-Config][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rArRE.png

Then I referenced the variable in the next sampler:
[Login Page Sampler][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhroP.png

When I run the Testplan I get a different __VIEWSTATE in the Login Page.

The ViewState from Debug Sampler - Tree View Listener:
[Debug Sempler][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXwb.png

Listener-Tree Start Page:
[Start Page][4]
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP0Mr.png

Listener-Tree Login Page:
[Login Page][5]
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p0dV.png

Comment: Sorry for the images, it didnt work out as planned:
1: [CSS Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rArRE.png)
2: [Login-Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhroP.png)
3: [Debug Sempler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXwb.png)
4: [Start Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP0Mr.png)
5: [Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p0dV.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. It's hard to say what's going on without seeing your test plan, most probably you're getting different values for your `${View}` variable due to this CSS Selector Extractor scope including more than one HTTP Request sampler so the value gets overwritten somewhere somehow so first of all I would recommend getting familiarized with [JMeter Scoping Rules concept](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide). In short words:

   - If you place the Post-Processor at the same level with several samplers - it will be applied to all the samplers
   - If you make the Post-Processor a child of a single sampler - it will be applied to this sampler only
2. You need to correlate this `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` value as well
3. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan and if you did already double check that it sends all the cookies which are being sent by the real browser

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, my Post-Processor is a child of a sampler, now I added another and correlated `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` aswell. HTTP Cookie Manager is (and was) also in my test plan. Still same result. I dont know where this could be overwritten..